# map headset button in gnome3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, gnome3, dbus

How can I map in gnome3 the button from my bluetooth headset?

Gnome sees a `AcceleratorActivated` event when I press it:

```
$ dbus-monitor --monitor
signal time=1525078944.868498 sender=:1.17 -> destination=:1.52 serial=2069 path=/org/gnome/Shell; interface=org.gnome.Shell; member=AcceleratorActivated
   uint32 152
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "device-id"
         variant             uint32 3
      )
      dict entry(
         string "timestamp"
         variant             uint32 61966125
      )
      dict entry(
         string "action-mode"
         variant             uint32 1
      )
   ]
```

But gnome doesn't do anything except showing an `"action-unavailable-symbolic"` icon in gnome's OSD (I use a dark gnome theme):

[image]

The following dbus `ShowOSD` even is seen at the same time:

```
$ dbus-monitor --monitor
method call time=1525078944.869555 sender=:1.52 -> destination=:1.17 serial=246 path=/org/gnome/Shell; interface=org.gnome.Shell; member=ShowOSD
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "icon"
         variant             string "action-unavailable-symbolic"
      )
   ]
```

The headset buttons aren't recognised by gnome in the usual keyboard mapping settings available at: `Settings`  > `keyboard`  > `Add Custom Shortcut` : although it works great with mapping keyboard keys, headset buttons are not detected by this tool when I press them, so I just can't use it to map headset button.

What I want to do is trigger play/pause when I press the headset button. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing `AcceleratorActivated` means that the key is *already* mapped to something; possibly to the built-in "play/pause" item. Otherwise it wouldn't have been submitted to gnome-shell during accelerator registration.

If you restart gnome-shell while watching the bus, you'll see a method call to `GrabAccelerators` containing all the key names, and a corresponding method_return containing accel IDs. With this you can decipher the ID from AcceleratorActivated, such as `152` in your case, back to the key combination. (It's very likely that the system already recognizes your button as `XF86AudioPlay`. And GNOME already has a default mapping for "XF86AudioPlay ⇒ play/pause via MPRIS".)

In that case, the ∅ OSD is shown if there is neither an MPRISv2-compatible player running which gnome-shell could forward the event to, nor a player using the old GNOME-specific functions for receiving media keys.

Comment: You're right, it was mapped to a MPRIS command, and play/pause as you suggested. Well done. It did indeed work out-of-the-box with VLC, but not with the other player I was using. Thanks!

Comment: For those who want to use mpris with youtube, there is really only one solution as of today: https://github.com/otommod/browser-mpris2